# How to change the color of one variable to another color with a predefined color palette with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I have a legend on the side of my map and want to user to be able to change the colors to a color of their choice from the predefined color fields. I'm using https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum for my color palette code. I'm just not sure how to now be able to give the use a choice to determine what color they want.

I have this so far:

```
    $('#showPaletteOnly').spectrum({
       shoPaletteOnly: true,
       showPalette: true,
       color: '#a6cee3',
       palette:[
          ['#a6cee3','#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99','#e31a1c','#fdbf6f','#ff7f00','#cab2d6','#6a3d9a','#ffff99','#b15928']
       ]
     });
```

I have a legend on the side of the map with 10 fields and each already have a color defined within the database. I'm assuming I just need a function to be able to do it but I'm not sure how to get it started. I googled before creating this and couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do if you want to keep the change in your DB:

on select of a new color by the user, update the entity in your DB with `$.post()` method : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( url, { entityId: entityId, color: newColor }, function(){

    $('#yourElement').css('color', newColor);
} );
```

if you dont have to update, just use the content of the callback function

setting your own values of course

Comment: thank you for your response. Am I able to use my code from above within the $.post? I want to be able to have the users choose a color from the palette and then save the new color

Comment: sure, you just have to "listen" to the change event on the palette, and find the value of the selected color. Just search in the docs ;)

Comment: so create a .change(function()) and then add my initial code in there and "listen" to the color change?

Comment: https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/issues/19 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463275/onchange-doesnt-fire-when-modified-by-javascript